# How to remove or stop ads from admob old app?

Tags: google-play, admob

Google play remove my account from play store. I have 20 app. Admob still generate ads revenue because that app was publish in  other unknown market and i have no rights to remove that. And I continuously got mail from admob that violating our police.

**I got mail is:**

Hello,

This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.

Issue ID#: *******

Ad serving has been disabled to: Video Player (com.***.*******)

Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your account for compliance.

Current account status: Active

Violation explanation

GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube, or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products, such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.

If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.

Action required: Check account for compliance
While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we continue to see violations occurring.

Appeals
If you wish to appeal this disabling then you can do so by using our appeal form.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Sincerely,

The Google AdMob Team

How to can i remove that app ads unit id from Admob?

And How to stop this thing because its admob warning that may disable my admob account?
Any suggestion ??

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue with admob / play store? I have received a similar email from them and not sure what the violation is.

Comment: Hi @Rank Mayur, Please let us know whether you solved the issue or not? If yes how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to remove it from the app and republish the app in the other market.

Answer (score 0):

At the Admob console, select the app with the ads.

[image]

check the ad you want to disable, then click < Archive >

this will give  you the prompt below.

[image]

this will disable your Ads with that Ad unit ID (I hope you didn't use the same ID for all 20 of your apps).

Comment: thank you Angel Koh, and yes I didn't used same ID for all app

Comment: @RankMayur, do accept the answer if it works for you.